# How to change an item in a list forever?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, listbox, storage

I have a program in tkinter which I have a list in it and I transferred the list items to a list box.
when I run it, there is a list box and you're able to change the items by pressing buttons and writing something in the Entry box.
here is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, ACTIVE, END
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("برنامهء مغازه")
window.geometry("900x500")
window.configure(background = "white")
window.resizable(width=False,height=False)

tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab_1 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab_2 = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
tab_parent.add(tab_1,text="خرید قسطی")
tab_parent.add(tab_2,text="کالاها")

def Update(data):
    list_box.delete(0,END)
    for item in data:
    list_box.insert(END,item)

def fillout(e):
    entry_search.delete(0,END)
    entry_search.insert(0,list_box.get(ACTIVE))

def check(e):
    typed = entry_search.get()
    if typed == "":
        data = products
    else:
        data = []
        for item in products:
            if typed in item:
                data.append(item)
    Update(data)

label_search = tk.Label(tab_2,text="جستجو")
label_search.grid(column=0,row=0)
label_search.pack()
entry_search = tk.Entry(tab_2,justify="right",width="60")
entry_search.pack(pady=5)
list_box = tk.Listbox(tab_2,justify="right",width="60")
list_box.pack(pady=15)

products = ["مخلوط کن دلمونتی",
"هم زن حرفه ای دلمونتی ",
"غذا ساز 4 کاره دلمونتی",
"آب مرکبات گیر دلمونتی"]
def edit():
    typed_2 = entry_search.get()
    if typed_2 == "":
    data = products
    elif typed_2 in products:
    global index_item_in_products
    index_item_in_products = products.index(typed_2)

def confirm():
    typed_3 = entry_search.get()
    products[index_item_in_products] = typed_3
    Update(products)

btn_edit = tk.Button(tab_2,text="ویرایش",command=edit)
btn_edit.pack(pady=5)
btn_edit_confirm = tk.Button(tab_2,text="تایید ویرایش",command=confirm)
btn_edit_confirm.pack(pady=10)

Update(products)
list_box.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",fillout)
entry_search.bind('<KeyRelease>',check)

tab_parent.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

But the problem is that when I rerun the code after changing an item ,the items are just the previous ones.
I expect that when I change an item, it will be saved in the memory(storing it) and when I rerun the program, the item is the changed one. what should I do?

Comment: If you need persistence, you will have to implement it.

Comment: your products are hardcoded in a list. When the program executes it initializes the products from this list. If you want to keep changes, store the products in a file or in a database, then when your program starts it should load the products from there, and not from a hardcoded list.

Comment: how can I store the products in a file or in a database?

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial: [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 1):

So the thing here is that your running the same code with the same hard coded values. You will have to store the list separately (in a different file). A common beginner friendly way to do this is with json. Take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Edit:
When the file starts up you can run a function such as

```py
def load_data(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data
```

you can then use the access the data like this  `data = load_data(json_file)`

to then save the data when you have made changes

```py
def save_data(data, file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
```

This will then be saves in the the same json file ready for when you start the file again.